# Filtrar tabla de pandas que contenga dos strings en un valor sin importar el orden en python

Tags: python, pandas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A partir de esta tabla me gustaría que buscando "Lionel Messi" me aparezca la primera fila, a pesar de que Lionel y Messi no vayan seguidos.

Haciendo esto me salen las filas que contienen en su 'long_name' tanto "lionel" como "messi"

```
filtro = ddatos[ddatos['long_name'].str.contains("lionel | messi", case=False)]
filtro
```

Entonces quiero algo parecido pero que solo me saque aquellos que contienen "lionel" y "messi" dentro de la columna "long_name" sin importar en que orden aparezcan.

He probado de la siguiente forma pero no me da ningún resultado

```
filtro = ddatos[ddatos['long_name'].str.contains("lionel & messi", case=False)]
filtro
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que le pasas como parámetro a `str.contains()` es una expresión regular. Por eso puedes usar el carácter  `|` para separar dos posibles opciones. Pero en cambio no puedes usar el carácter `&` porque no se trata de operaciones lógicas, las expresiones regulares no funcionan así.

Para encontrar tanto "lionel" como "messi" con una sola expresión regular puedes usar por ejemplo:

```
"lionel.*messi|messi.*lionel"
```

Como ves, el truco es especificar como opciones para el `|` los dos diferentes órdenes en que pueden aparecer (el `.*` entre ambas es para que acepte también cualquier secuencia de caracteres que pueda aparecer entre esas dos palabras).

Sin embargo si quieres mirar más de dos palabras, este truco no escala bien ya que tendrías que especificar todos los posibles órdenes en que las palabras puedan aparecer. Para un caso así valdría mas no usar expresiones regulares, sino escribir una función que te mire si todas las palabras están o no en la cadena (por ejemplo usando un bucle que itere por las palabras y verifique una a una si está `in` la cadena dada, retornando `False` tan pronto como encuentre una que no, o `True` si las encuentra todas). Esa función podrías usarla como argumento a un `df.apply()` y el resultado (una columna de booleanos) usarlo para filtrar las filas deseadas.

Un ejemplo de esto último (insisto, tendría sentido si la lista de nombres a buscar fuese más larga, para solo dos quizás sea excesivo):

```
def contiene_palabras(texto, palabras):
  for palabra in palabras:
    if palabra.lower() not in texto.lower():
      return False
  return True

ddatos[ddatos.long_name.apply(lambda txt: contiene_palabras(txt, ["lionel", "messi"])]
```

Answer (score 3):

Si he entendido bien, lo que quieres sacar es una lista en la que esté "lionel messi" de esta manera no? Hay varias posibilidades de ver que está vacío, la primera es que no haya ningún dato como tu deseas. Otra es que al hacer el contains con el and dentro de la misma instrucción, te está buscando los que son exactamente iguales a "lionel" y a "messi".

Si deseas que salga cuando solo sea lionel messi prueba con esto:

```
filtro = ddatos[(ddatos["long_name"].str.contains("lionel")) & (ddatos["long_name"].str.contains("messi"))]

PD. No pongas imágenes que no es legible.
```